# Java File Splitting

Tags: java, file, split

What will be the most eficient way to split a file in Java ?
Like to get it grid ready...

(Edit)
Modifying the question.
Basically after scouring the net I understand that there are generally two methods followed for file splitting....

1. Just split them by the number of bytes

   I guess the advantage of this method is that it is fast, but say I have all the data  in a line and suppose the file split puts half the data in one split and the other half the data in another split, then what do I do ??
2. Read them line by line

   This will keep my data intact, fine, but I suppose this ain't as fast as the above method

Comment: More details would be appreciated. What do you want to do? How do you want to split the file?

Comment: Now that you've modified your question, you've already answered it yourself. What you say is basically correct, there's not much to add now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first impression is that you have something like a *comma separated value* (csv) file. The usual way to read / parse those files is to

- read them line by line
- skip headers and empty lines
- use `String#split(String reg)` to split a line into values (reg is chosen to match the delimiter)

Comment: Well, unless the file has commas in it, that would become a problem

Comment: @asperous.us - the strategy works with any delimeter. A delimter char or sequence must not be substring of any value, but thats a usual condition for csv files.

Answer (score 3):

Well, just read the file line by line and start saving it to a new file. Then when you decide it's time to split, start saving the lines to a new place.

Don't worry about efficiency too much unless it's a real problem later.